# How to make pdf, ppt and videos not downloadable and just view them in browser when clicked

Tags: html, pdf, video, powerpoint

I am working on a web application, where am uploading pdfs, ppts and videos(.mp4) to my location on the server and just displaying the links to them.
And when the user clicks on these links it should be opened in a new tab and  make them not downloadable too.

So below are the things which am stuck with:

- The pdf's link do open in a new tab , but I still can download them.
- On clicking the PPT file link it directly downloads to my local drive, instead i want to make it open in a new tab and also it shouldn't be downloadable.
- Same goes for the videos as well, I want to make them not downloadable and just open in an other tab.

Please help me with this, if there is any solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably stop someone downloading a file if you are making it available to view on the browser - one way or the other, the file has to make it to the browser and there are many techniques to capture and store the file.

If the content security important to you then the usual approach is to encrypt the files so they are no use even if they are downloaded and use a DRM system to share the key between the server and the browsers. There are free 'clearkey' DRM schemes which include the key in the file, and hence are not as secure, but which may be good enough for your requirements.

If you are concerned about the information being very sensitive, rather than avoiding people creating high quality copies, then ultimately there is nothing to stop someone simply recording the screen with an external camera.

Answer (score 0):

use **target_blank** to open files in new tab

```html
<a href="file1.pdf" target="_blank">Open pdf</a>
    <a href="pptfile.ppt" target="_blank">Open ppt</a>

    <a href="video.mp4" target="_blank">Open Video</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but am already using this for this links. But only for ppts , itseems to just download to my local drive and it doesn't open in a new tab. Any ideas or suggestions to make it open in a new tab?